# How to store values in NSUserDefaults like as a Database?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need to create an application using `NSUserDefaults`.

In my first view I will enter the password. In second view I will enter the confirm password. Then validation will happen; after then if password will be match in both views, then success window will open.  After then some views will come. I need that password should be save in `NSUserDefaults` for future use.

If I will close my application after validation, then if I will build and run again my application now the password validation window should not be open.

Only one view simply will ask the password, if the current password is equal to before terminate application's password, then the application's success view will be open. Now here the validation should be compare with current password with `NSUserDefaults`'s value[i.e old password, which is stored before terminate my application].

It is possible to using `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Objective-C:**

To save in Defaults

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

To retrieve

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

**Swift:**

```
var userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject("TextToSave", forKey: "keyToLookupString")
//To retrieve
let mySavedObject = userDefaults.objectForKey(@"keyToLookupString")
```

Anyway just a hint do not store passwords in NSUserdefaults. Use keychain for storing secure data.

Answer (score 8):

Do not use NSUserDefaults to hold user passwords!  It is not secure.  You should store passwords in the keychain where it is encrypted, there's small wrapper class that makes saving username/password into the keychain very easy:

http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code

Comment: Not technically an answer to the question, but better advice.