# Issues with totaling numbers in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the best way to plan my model for totaling numbers? Should I use Arrays or Dictionaries?

In my app I want to be able to total a group of numbers over a period of time. Lets say I have 2 textFields that subract numbers and offer a total. That is working fine but I want to take that total everything by hitting a button.

Example: users enter

256789 in the start field
256798 in the end field

Then I get the total of 9.

Should I save nine in an array or dictionary with a key total?
I want 9 to be used later.

for example:

Now the user opens the app and types two different numbers in the start and end field and gets a total of 20.

How can I add the total of 9 to 20.

What's the best way to keep track of these numbers?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4270259/1328096

Comment: Please, please, please learn to program first.

Comment: sorry I don't get it and I don't see a technical problem here anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of them (NSDictionary and NSArray), look at KVC guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

You are specifically looking for @sum operator, this is @sum section from the link above:

> @sum
>
> The @sum operator returns the sum of the values of the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator. Each number is converted to a double, the sum of the values is computed, and the total is wrapped as an instance of NSNumber and returned. If the value
>   of the right side of the key path is nil, it is ignored.
>
> The following example returns the sum of the amounts property for the transactions in transactions:

```
NSNumber *amountSum = [transactions valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
```

> The resulting amountSum value (formatted) is $5,935.00.

Comment: I've seen that guide and thank you but I seem to alwyas get this collection isn't key value compliant. I can only add 1 total at a time in a dictionary right? can this total multiple dictionaries. Instead of having total equals 9 i want to have several totals to add all together such at total 9 total 10 total 11. How can I accomplish this with a dictionary?

Comment: im having trouble understanding what you mean. i thought from your question that you will store computation results in an array or dictionary, then you will sum them. this @sum operator works for that, if you use nsdictionary keypath is @"@sum.yourPropertyName" if nsarray keypath is @"@sum.floatValue".

Comment: How can I accomplish this using a dictionary of user input. The app is a mileage app so the user enters the start mileage and the ending mileage then has a total miles traveled. I want to be able to add the total miles traveled up to get a grand total.

Comment: can you give some sample source code of how this can work with a dictionary.

Comment: can there be multiple total fields in a dictionary or just one per dictionary.. As in can I have 10 totals for the key total in a dictionary

Comment: you can only use a key once, but the object that key refers to can be an nsarray holding 10 values (totals). then the summing would be done by `NSNumber *amountSum = [yourDict valueForKeyPath:@"yourTotalsKey.@sum.floatValue"];`

Comment: I think it dumb to use KVC and stuff like `@sum` when you haven't the foggiest what you're doing.  It's counter-productive to actually learning to program.

Comment: Hot licks, I've used @sum before in an NSARray before so I know what I'm doing with kvc. I had trouble with one aspect of my program which is totaling numbers and what would be the best method.

Comment: Guenis 6 and all others that contributed to this question in a positive way thank you. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Dictionary because it allows you to assign your own labels for use later on. A quick example being:

```
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:42] forKey:@"Round 1 number A"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12] forKey:@"Round 1 number B"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:54] forKey:@"Round 1 total"];

[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:11] forKey:@"Round 2 number A"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:33] forKey:@"Round 2 number B"];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:44] forKey:@"Round 2 total"];
```

etc....

This makes keeping track a lot easier, IMHO.